# localeCompare method behaving ambiguously

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I have two strings **x**="a_shok" and **y**="a.pl". When I'm doing simple **x < y** then I get false as an output on console, however if I'm using **x.localeCompare(y)** then I'm getting -1 as the output. Why is javascript behaving so ambiguously ?

PS: I'm expecting "a.pl" to come before "a_shok"

Comment: And why is that ?

Comment: Please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: I'm still confused. What changes should i make to get the expected result ??

Comment: Because `<` compares code unit, which may not be lexical, and *localeCompare* uses "dictionary" order for the particular language. Try `'a' < 'B'` vs `'a'.localeCompare('B')`. In code units, "a" is > "B", but in a dictionary "a" comes before (is less than) "B".

Comment: You do expect it because to you `.` is lower than `_` ? if you want a sorting not being influenced by special chars, remove special chars and then compare them

Comment: @RobG so what changes should i make then ?? Should i write my own algorithm to match strings ?

Comment: If you want an order different to the default for the method you're trying to use, yes. What other option is there?

Comment: @RobG Yeah !! I don't have any other option rather than writing my custom algorithm.

Comment: If you want special characters ignored, do as quirimmo suggested and remove them for the comparison.